# 000webhost don't show my css, js, image files

Tags: laravel

My Laravel project run correctly on my localhost but when I upload on 000webhost it just show me html data and css,js,images file don't. This is a example about css files, I use this to link css files:

```
<link href="{{asset('public/frontend/css/bootstrap.min.css')}}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Here is my file structure

```
-app
-bootstrap
-config
-database
-public
 --frontend
  ---css
   ----bootstrap.min.css
   ----some files css in here
  ---fonts
  ---images
  ---js
-public_html
-resources
 --views
   ---index.blade.php
-routes
-storage
...
```

When I run it take 2 errors:

> Refused to apply style from
> 'https://...000webhostapp.com/public/frontend/css/bootstrap.min.css'
> because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME
> type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

And

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

All css,js,image files have 2 errors.

Comment: Generally, you would not need to include `public/` when referencing assets as that directory should be defined as the web root for your domain.  What is the address of your home page? (`https://...000webhostapp.com/` or `https://...000webhostapp.com/public/`) And what is set as `APP_URL` in the `.env` file?

Comment: I tried erase all ``public/`` but it still don't work. My home page is ``https://...000webhostapp.com/`` and ``APP_URL`` is ``http://localhost``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!! I really don't understand but i just move `public` folder into `public_html` folder and it worked